# Missing Dependency ROS kinetic kame

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi first time ROS user here.
Im having issue installing ROS Kinetic to Ubuntu Xenial.
I'm following the guide here: http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu

I ran:

> sudo apt-get update

The result:

> Ign:1
> http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb
> stable InRelease
> Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb
> stable Release                Get:3
> http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu
> xenial InRelease [11.5 kB]      Get:5
> http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu
> xenial/partner amd64 Packages [3,340
> B] Get:6
> http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu
> xenial/partner i386 Packages [3,620 B]
> Get:7
> http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu
> xenial/partner Translation-en [1,964
> B] Hit:8
> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> xenial InRelease
> Hit:9
> http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu
> xenial InRelease
> Fetched 20.4 kB in 5s (3,794 B/s)
> Reading package lists... Done N:
> Skipping acquire of configured file
> 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as
> repository
> 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb
> stable InRelease' doesn't support
> architecture 'i386'

Then when i run the install

sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-kinetic-desktop-full : Depends: ros-kinetic-desktop but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-kinetic-perception but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-kinetic-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261884/missing-dependency-ros-kinetic-kame/) by [kennyalpha](https://answers.ros.org/users/30417/kennyalpha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-05-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-05-17**:
Try upgrading first (apt-get dist-upgrade)

**Comment by [kennyalpha](https://answers.ros.org/users/30417/kennyalpha/) on 2017-05-17**:
I tried this, still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi:

Have you installed Gazebo before installing ROS?
If yes, then it is likely because the Gazebo installation, see the solution [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15568/ros-kinetic-desktop-full-can-not-be-installed-after-installing-gazebo/)

Best,
tor

---

Originally posted by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) with karma: 277 on 2017-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0